# Line break using Mathjax HTML

Tags: line-breaks, mathjax

I am trying to break math which rendered in Mathjax(HTML). After breaking it, found a leading(space between two lines) issue. Provided the HTML for your review. I need a suggestion to get the correct leading.

I am looking for a solution like height:100%, height:auto, height:fit-content, etc.

Just for your reference, The below mentioned two elements defines the height. `<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -1.622em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 3.941em;" class="style1"></span> <span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;" class="style2"></span>`

Mathjax Version: 2.7.5
line-break option: disabled.

```
SAMPLE LINK: https://jsfiddle.net/26opzc1k/
```

Note: This is a sample only, I've to break more equations.

Comment: The leading isn't incorrect, it's just accounting for overset and underset symbols regardless of whether they exist in a given line. You can hack it by defining a style for `.old-container` (`.old-container { margin-top: -1rem;}`) but doing so is the equivalent of adjusting the leading of each line in a paragraph based on whether they have ascenders or descenders.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I am looking for a solution like height:100%, height:auto, height:fit-content, etc.

Comment: Just for your reference, The below mentioned two elements defines the height.

`<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -1.622em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 3.941em;" class="style1"></span>
<span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;" class="style2"></span>`

Comment: If you want to just change the height then `.old-container` is still the element to do that on, but as I said in my first comment, you will encounter overlapping underset and overset symbols. `.old-container { height: 2.5rem}`

Answer (score 0):

The leading isn't incorrect, it's just accounting for overset and underset symbols regardless of whether they exist in a given line. You can hack it by defining a style for `.old-container` (`.old-container { margin-top: -1rem;}`) – but doing so will likely result in overlapping symbols, and adjusting each line individually is the equivalent of adjusting the leading of each line in a paragraph based on whether they have ascenders or descenders or not.

Adjusting height of `.old-container`

```css
.old-container {
  height: 2.5rem;
 }
```

```html
<tr>
    <td align="center"><div class="equation"><div class="old-container"><div class="MathJax_Display" style="text-align: center;"><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-35-Frame" tabindex="0" data-mathml="" role="presentation" style="text-align: center; position: relative;"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-2843" overflow="scroll" style="width: 180.822em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 155.876em; height: 0px; font-size: 116%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1.888em, 1155.71em, 5.498em, -999.997em); top: -3.984em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2844"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2863"><span class="broken" id="MathJax-Span-2891" style="font-family: MathJax_Main; padding-left: 0.164em;">−</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2892" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">,</span><span class="msup" id="MathJax-Span-2893" style="padding-left: 0.164em;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 1.134em; height: 0px;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.397em, 1000.49em, 4.367em, -999.997em); top: -3.984em; left: 0em;"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2894" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">η<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; top: -4.415em; left: 0.541em;"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2895" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">T<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.11em;"></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2896" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">,</span><span class="mfenced" id="MathJax-Span-2897"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2943" style=""><span style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">(</span></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2899" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">k</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2944" style=""><span style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">)</span></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2901" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">,</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2902" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic; padding-left: 0.164em;">P<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.11em;"></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2903" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">,</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2904" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic; padding-left: 0.164em;">η<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2905" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">,</span><span class="mfenced" id="MathJax-Span-2906"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2945" style=""><span style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">(</span></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2908" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">k</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2946" style=""><span style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">)</span></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2910" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: MathJax_Size1;">}</span></span></span><span class="mo gbk" id="MathJax-Span-2911" style="font-family: MathJax_Main; padding-left: 0.272em;">=</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2912" style="font-family: MathJax_AMS; padding-left: 0.272em;">E</span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2913"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2914" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: MathJax_Size4;">{</span></span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2915"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2916" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: MathJax_Size4;">[</span></span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2917"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2918" style="font-family: MathJax_Script;">A<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.218em;"></span></span><span class="mo gbk" id="MathJax-Span-2947"></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2948" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic; padding-left: 0.164em;">η<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span class="mo bbk" id="MathJax-Span-2949"></span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2950"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2951" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">(</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2952" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">k</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2953" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">)</span></span></span></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;" class="style2"></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;" class="style2"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -1.622em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 3.941em;" class="style1"></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -1.622em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 3.941em;" class="style1"></span></span></nobr></span></div></div><div class="old-container"><div class="MathJax_Display" style="text-align: center;"><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-35-Frame" tabindex="0" data-mathml="" role="presentation" style="text-align: center; position: relative;"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-2843" overflow="scroll" style="width: 180.822em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 155.876em; height: 0px; font-size: 116%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1.888em, 1155.71em, 5.498em, -999.997em); top: -3.984em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2844"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2913"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2915"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2917"><span class="broken" id="MathJax-Span-2954" style="font-family: MathJax_Main; padding-left: 0.218em;">+</span><span class="msub" id="MathJax-Span-2955" style="padding-left: 0.218em;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 1.08em; height: 0px;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.397em, 1000.6em, 4.151em, -999.997em); top: -3.984em; left: 0em;"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2956" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">α</span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; top: -3.823em; left: 0.649em;"><span class="mn" id="MathJax-Span-2957" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">1</span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span></span></span><span class="mo gbk" id="MathJax-Span-2958"></span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2959" style="padding-left: 0.164em;"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2960" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">(</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2961" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">k</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2962" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">)</span></span><span class="mo gbk" id="MathJax-Span-2963" style="padding-left: 0.164em;"></span><span class="msub" id="MathJax-Span-2964"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 1.08em; height: 0px;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.074em, 1000.81em, 4.151em, -999.997em); top: -3.984em; left: 0em;"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2965" style="font-family: MathJax_Script;">C<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.164em;"></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; top: -3.823em; left: 0.649em;"><span class="mn" id="MathJax-Span-2966" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">1</span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span></span></span><span class="mo gbk" id="MathJax-Span-2967"></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2968" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic; padding-left: 0.164em;">η<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span class="mo bbk" id="MathJax-Span-2969"></span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2970"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2971" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">(</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2972" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">k</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2973" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">)</span></span><span class="mo gbk" id="MathJax-Span-2974" style="font-family: MathJax_Main; padding-left: 0.218em;">+</span><span class="munderover" id="MathJax-Span-2975" embellished="∑" style="padding-left: 0.218em;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 1.457em; height: 0px;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(2.858em, 1001.4em, 4.582em, -999.997em); top: -3.984em; left: 0em;"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2976" style="font-family: MathJax_Size2; vertical-align: 0em;">∑</span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.343em, 1001.24em, 4.367em, -999.997em); top: -2.907em; left: 0.11em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2977"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2978" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">p</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2979" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">=</span><span class="mn" id="MathJax-Span-2980" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">2</span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.235em, 1000.76em, 4.151em, -999.997em); top: -5.116em; left: 0.38em;"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2981" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">M<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.057em;"></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span></span></span><span class="mo gbk" id="MathJax-Span-2982" style="padding-left: 0.164em;"></span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2983" style="padding-left: 0.164em;"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2984" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: MathJax_Size4;">{</span></span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2985"><span class="munderover" id="MathJax-Span-2986" embellished="∏"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 1.296em; height: 0px;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(2.858em, 1001.24em, 4.582em, -999.997em); top: -3.984em; left: 0em;"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2987" style="font-family: MathJax_Size2; vertical-align: 0em;">∏</span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.343em, 1001.19em, 4.367em, -999.997em); top: -2.907em; left: 0.003em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2988"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2989" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">q<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2990" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">=</span><span class="mn" id="MathJax-Span-2991" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">1</span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.235em, 1001.19em, 4.313em, -999.997em); top: -5.17em; left: 0.003em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2992"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2993" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">p</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2994" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">−</span><span class="mn" id="MathJax-Span-2995" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">1</span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;" class="style2"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -1.622em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 3.941em;" class="style1"></span></span></nobr></span></div></div></div></td></tr>
```

Adjusting margin of `.old-container`

```css
.old-container {
  margin-top: -1.3rem;
}
```

```html
<tr>
    <td align="center"><div class="equation"><div class="old-container"><div class="MathJax_Display" style="text-align: center;"><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-35-Frame" tabindex="0" data-mathml="" role="presentation" style="text-align: center; position: relative;"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-2843" overflow="scroll" style="width: 180.822em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 155.876em; height: 0px; font-size: 116%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1.888em, 1155.71em, 5.498em, -999.997em); top: -3.984em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2844"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2863"><span class="broken" id="MathJax-Span-2891" style="font-family: MathJax_Main; padding-left: 0.164em;">−</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2892" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">,</span><span class="msup" id="MathJax-Span-2893" style="padding-left: 0.164em;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 1.134em; height: 0px;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.397em, 1000.49em, 4.367em, -999.997em); top: -3.984em; left: 0em;"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2894" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">η<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; top: -4.415em; left: 0.541em;"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2895" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">T<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.11em;"></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2896" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">,</span><span class="mfenced" id="MathJax-Span-2897"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2943" style=""><span style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">(</span></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2899" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">k</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2944" style=""><span style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">)</span></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2901" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">,</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2902" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic; padding-left: 0.164em;">P<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.11em;"></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2903" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">,</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2904" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic; padding-left: 0.164em;">η<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2905" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">,</span><span class="mfenced" id="MathJax-Span-2906"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2945" style=""><span style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">(</span></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2908" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">k</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2946" style=""><span style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">)</span></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2910" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: MathJax_Size1;">}</span></span></span><span class="mo gbk" id="MathJax-Span-2911" style="font-family: MathJax_Main; padding-left: 0.272em;">=</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2912" style="font-family: MathJax_AMS; padding-left: 0.272em;">E</span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2913"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2914" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: MathJax_Size4;">{</span></span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2915"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2916" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: MathJax_Size4;">[</span></span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2917"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2918" style="font-family: MathJax_Script;">A<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.218em;"></span></span><span class="mo gbk" id="MathJax-Span-2947"></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2948" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic; padding-left: 0.164em;">η<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span class="mo bbk" id="MathJax-Span-2949"></span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2950"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2951" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">(</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2952" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">k</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2953" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">)</span></span></span></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;" class="style2"></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;" class="style2"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -1.622em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 3.941em;" class="style1"></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -1.622em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 3.941em;" class="style1"></span></span></nobr></span></div></div><div class="old-container"><div class="MathJax_Display" style="text-align: center;"><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-35-Frame" tabindex="0" data-mathml="" role="presentation" style="text-align: center; position: relative;"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-2843" overflow="scroll" style="width: 180.822em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 155.876em; height: 0px; font-size: 116%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1.888em, 1155.71em, 5.498em, -999.997em); top: -3.984em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2844"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2913"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2915"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2917"><span class="broken" id="MathJax-Span-2954" style="font-family: MathJax_Main; padding-left: 0.218em;">+</span><span class="msub" id="MathJax-Span-2955" style="padding-left: 0.218em;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 1.08em; height: 0px;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.397em, 1000.6em, 4.151em, -999.997em); top: -3.984em; left: 0em;"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2956" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">α</span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; top: -3.823em; left: 0.649em;"><span class="mn" id="MathJax-Span-2957" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">1</span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span></span></span><span class="mo gbk" id="MathJax-Span-2958"></span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2959" style="padding-left: 0.164em;"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2960" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">(</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2961" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">k</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2962" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">)</span></span><span class="mo gbk" id="MathJax-Span-2963" style="padding-left: 0.164em;"></span><span class="msub" id="MathJax-Span-2964"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 1.08em; height: 0px;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.074em, 1000.81em, 4.151em, -999.997em); top: -3.984em; left: 0em;"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2965" style="font-family: MathJax_Script;">C<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.164em;"></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; top: -3.823em; left: 0.649em;"><span class="mn" id="MathJax-Span-2966" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">1</span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span></span></span><span class="mo gbk" id="MathJax-Span-2967"></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2968" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic; padding-left: 0.164em;">η<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span class="mo bbk" id="MathJax-Span-2969"></span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2970"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2971" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">(</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2972" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">k</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2973" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">)</span></span><span class="mo gbk" id="MathJax-Span-2974" style="font-family: MathJax_Main; padding-left: 0.218em;">+</span><span class="munderover" id="MathJax-Span-2975" embellished="∑" style="padding-left: 0.218em;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 1.457em; height: 0px;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(2.858em, 1001.4em, 4.582em, -999.997em); top: -3.984em; left: 0em;"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2976" style="font-family: MathJax_Size2; vertical-align: 0em;">∑</span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.343em, 1001.24em, 4.367em, -999.997em); top: -2.907em; left: 0.11em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2977"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2978" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">p</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2979" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">=</span><span class="mn" id="MathJax-Span-2980" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">2</span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.235em, 1000.76em, 4.151em, -999.997em); top: -5.116em; left: 0.38em;"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2981" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">M<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.057em;"></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span></span></span><span class="mo gbk" id="MathJax-Span-2982" style="padding-left: 0.164em;"></span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2983" style="padding-left: 0.164em;"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2984" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: MathJax_Size4;">{</span></span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2985"><span class="munderover" id="MathJax-Span-2986" embellished="∏"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 1.296em; height: 0px;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(2.858em, 1001.24em, 4.582em, -999.997em); top: -3.984em; left: 0em;"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2987" style="font-family: MathJax_Size2; vertical-align: 0em;">∏</span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.343em, 1001.19em, 4.367em, -999.997em); top: -2.907em; left: 0.003em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2988"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2989" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">q<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2990" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">=</span><span class="mn" id="MathJax-Span-2991" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">1</span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.235em, 1001.19em, 4.313em, -999.997em); top: -5.17em; left: 0.003em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2992"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2993" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">p</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2994" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">−</span><span class="mn" id="MathJax-Span-2995" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">1</span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;" class="style2"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -1.622em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 3.941em;" class="style1"></span></span></nobr></span></div></div></div></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have edited the question to focus on the two span elements that specify the internal height of each line. These elements use inline styles so in order to override them you need to use `...!important`.

`.style1` allows you to adjust the space between lines.

`.style2` adjusts the placement of the line in the container, but adjusting it from it's original value causes overflow to be cutoff.

Ultimately this solution offers no more control than my previous answer utilizing `.old-container` and still doesn't solve the problem of possible overlapping underset and overset symbols.

```css
.style1 {
  height: 2.5em !important;
}

.style2 {
  height: 3.99em !important;
}
```

```html
<tr>
    <td align="center"><div class="equation"><div class="old-container"><div class="MathJax_Display" style="text-align: center;"><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-35-Frame" tabindex="0" data-mathml="" role="presentation" style="text-align: center; position: relative;"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-2843" overflow="scroll" style="width: 180.822em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 155.876em; height: 0px; font-size: 116%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1.888em, 1155.71em, 5.498em, -999.997em); top: -3.984em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2844"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2863"><span class="broken" id="MathJax-Span-2891" style="font-family: MathJax_Main; padding-left: 0.164em;">−</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2892" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">,</span><span class="msup" id="MathJax-Span-2893" style="padding-left: 0.164em;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 1.134em; height: 0px;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.397em, 1000.49em, 4.367em, -999.997em); top: -3.984em; left: 0em;"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2894" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">η<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; top: -4.415em; left: 0.541em;"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2895" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">T<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.11em;"></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2896" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">,</span><span class="mfenced" id="MathJax-Span-2897"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2943" style=""><span style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">(</span></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2899" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">k</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2944" style=""><span style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">)</span></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2901" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">,</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2902" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic; padding-left: 0.164em;">P<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.11em;"></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2903" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">,</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2904" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic; padding-left: 0.164em;">η<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2905" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">,</span><span class="mfenced" id="MathJax-Span-2906"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2945" style=""><span style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">(</span></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2908" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">k</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2946" style=""><span style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">)</span></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2910" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: MathJax_Size1;">}</span></span></span><span class="mo gbk" id="MathJax-Span-2911" style="font-family: MathJax_Main; padding-left: 0.272em;">=</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2912" style="font-family: MathJax_AMS; padding-left: 0.272em;">E</span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2913"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2914" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: MathJax_Size4;">{</span></span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2915"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2916" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: MathJax_Size4;">[</span></span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2917"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2918" style="font-family: MathJax_Script;">A<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.218em;"></span></span><span class="mo gbk" id="MathJax-Span-2947"></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2948" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic; padding-left: 0.164em;">η<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span class="mo bbk" id="MathJax-Span-2949"></span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2950"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2951" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">(</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2952" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">k</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2953" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">)</span></span></span></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;" class="style2"></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;" class="style2"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -1.622em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 3.941em;" class="style1"></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -1.622em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 3.941em;" class="style1"></span></span></nobr></span></div></div><div class="old-container"><div class="MathJax_Display" style="text-align: center;"><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-35-Frame" tabindex="0" data-mathml="" role="presentation" style="text-align: center; position: relative;"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-2843" overflow="scroll" style="width: 180.822em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 155.876em; height: 0px; font-size: 116%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1.888em, 1155.71em, 5.498em, -999.997em); top: -3.984em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2844"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2913"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2915"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2917"><span class="broken" id="MathJax-Span-2954" style="font-family: MathJax_Main; padding-left: 0.218em;">+</span><span class="msub" id="MathJax-Span-2955" style="padding-left: 0.218em;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 1.08em; height: 0px;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.397em, 1000.6em, 4.151em, -999.997em); top: -3.984em; left: 0em;"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2956" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">α</span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; top: -3.823em; left: 0.649em;"><span class="mn" id="MathJax-Span-2957" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">1</span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span></span></span><span class="mo gbk" id="MathJax-Span-2958"></span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2959" style="padding-left: 0.164em;"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2960" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">(</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2961" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">k</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2962" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">)</span></span><span class="mo gbk" id="MathJax-Span-2963" style="padding-left: 0.164em;"></span><span class="msub" id="MathJax-Span-2964"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 1.08em; height: 0px;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.074em, 1000.81em, 4.151em, -999.997em); top: -3.984em; left: 0em;"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2965" style="font-family: MathJax_Script;">C<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.164em;"></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; top: -3.823em; left: 0.649em;"><span class="mn" id="MathJax-Span-2966" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">1</span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span></span></span><span class="mo gbk" id="MathJax-Span-2967"></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2968" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic; padding-left: 0.164em;">η<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span class="mo bbk" id="MathJax-Span-2969"></span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2970"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2971" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">(</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2972" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">k</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2973" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">)</span></span><span class="mo gbk" id="MathJax-Span-2974" style="font-family: MathJax_Main; padding-left: 0.218em;">+</span><span class="munderover" id="MathJax-Span-2975" embellished="∑" style="padding-left: 0.218em;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 1.457em; height: 0px;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(2.858em, 1001.4em, 4.582em, -999.997em); top: -3.984em; left: 0em;"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2976" style="font-family: MathJax_Size2; vertical-align: 0em;">∑</span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.343em, 1001.24em, 4.367em, -999.997em); top: -2.907em; left: 0.11em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2977"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2978" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">p</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2979" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">=</span><span class="mn" id="MathJax-Span-2980" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">2</span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.235em, 1000.76em, 4.151em, -999.997em); top: -5.116em; left: 0.38em;"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2981" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">M<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.057em;"></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span></span></span><span class="mo gbk" id="MathJax-Span-2982" style="padding-left: 0.164em;"></span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2983" style="padding-left: 0.164em;"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2984" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: MathJax_Size4;">{</span></span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2985"><span class="munderover" id="MathJax-Span-2986" embellished="∏"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 1.296em; height: 0px;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(2.858em, 1001.24em, 4.582em, -999.997em); top: -3.984em; left: 0em;"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2987" style="font-family: MathJax_Size2; vertical-align: 0em;">∏</span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.343em, 1001.19em, 4.367em, -999.997em); top: -2.907em; left: 0.003em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2988"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2989" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">q<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2990" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">=</span><span class="mn" id="MathJax-Span-2991" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">1</span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.235em, 1001.19em, 4.313em, -999.997em); top: -5.17em; left: 0.003em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2992"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2993" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">p</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2994" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">−</span><span class="mn" id="MathJax-Span-2995" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">1</span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;" class="style2"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -1.622em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 3.941em;" class="style1"></span></span></nobr></span></div></div></div></td></tr>
```

There is no CSS silver bullet for this given that each line is made up of deeply nested, absolutely positioned spans. The simple CSS options I've provided so far are the least fragile and the most easily adjusted.

The following snippet illustrates adjusting each line's height based on whether or not it has overset or underset symbols. It queries the child elements of each `.old-container` for spans of class `.munderover` and adds a relevant class to the `.old-container` div which can then be styled appropriately.

This is a convoluted and fragile solution, but it does give you more fine grained control.

```js
const oldContainers = document.querySelectorAll('div.old-container, div.container');
oldContainers.forEach(div => {
  const overUnders = div.querySelectorAll('.munderover');
  if (!overUnders.length) {
    div.classList.add("no-over-under");
  } else {
    div.classList.add("over-under");
  }
});
```

```css
.old-container.no-over-under, .container.no-over-under{
   margin-top: -1.8em;
   margin-bottom: 0.4em;
}

.old-container.over-under, .container.over-under {
  margin-top: -1.2em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding: 16px;">
<tr>
    <td align="center"><div class="equation"><div class="old-container"><div class="MathJax_Display" style="text-align: center;"><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-35-Frame" tabindex="0" data-mathml="" role="presentation" style="text-align: center; position: relative;"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-2843" overflow="scroll" style="width: 180.822em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 155.876em; height: 0px; font-size: 116%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1.888em, 1155.71em, 5.498em, -999.997em); top: -3.984em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2844"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2863"><span class="broken" id="MathJax-Span-2891" style="font-family: MathJax_Main; padding-left: 0.164em;">−</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2892" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">,</span><span class="msup" id="MathJax-Span-2893" style="padding-left: 0.164em;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 1.134em; height: 0px;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.397em, 1000.49em, 4.367em, -999.997em); top: -3.984em; left: 0em;"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2894" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">η<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; top: -4.415em; left: 0.541em;"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2895" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">T<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.11em;"></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2896" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">,</span><span class="mfenced" id="MathJax-Span-2897"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2943" style=""><span style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">(</span></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2899" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">k</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2944" style=""><span style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">)</span></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2901" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">,</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2902" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic; padding-left: 0.164em;">P<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.11em;"></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2903" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">,</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2904" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic; padding-left: 0.164em;">η<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2905" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">,</span><span class="mfenced" id="MathJax-Span-2906"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2945" style=""><span style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">(</span></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2908" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">k</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2946" style=""><span style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">)</span></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2910" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: MathJax_Size1;">}</span></span></span><span class="mo gbk" id="MathJax-Span-2911" style="font-family: MathJax_Main; padding-left: 0.272em;">=</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2912" style="font-family: MathJax_AMS; padding-left: 0.272em;">E</span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2913"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2914" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: MathJax_Size4;">{</span></span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2915"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2916" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: MathJax_Size4;">[</span></span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2917"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2918" style="font-family: MathJax_Script;">A<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.218em;"></span></span><span class="mo gbk" id="MathJax-Span-2947"></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2948" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic; padding-left: 0.164em;">η<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span class="mo bbk" id="MathJax-Span-2949"></span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2950"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2951" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">(</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2952" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">k</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2953" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">)</span></span></span></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;" class="style2"></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;" class="style2"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -1.622em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 3.941em;" class="style1"></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -1.622em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 3.941em;" class="style1"></span></span></nobr></span></div></div><div class="old-container"><div class="MathJax_Display" style="text-align: center;"><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-35-Frame" tabindex="0" data-mathml="" role="presentation" style="text-align: center; position: relative;"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-2843" overflow="scroll" style="width: 180.822em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 155.876em; height: 0px; font-size: 116%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1.888em, 1155.71em, 5.498em, -999.997em); top: -3.984em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2844"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2913"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2915"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2917"><span class="broken" id="MathJax-Span-2954" style="font-family: MathJax_Main; padding-left: 0.218em;">+</span><span class="msub" id="MathJax-Span-2955" style="padding-left: 0.218em;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 1.08em; height: 0px;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.397em, 1000.6em, 4.151em, -999.997em); top: -3.984em; left: 0em;"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2956" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">α</span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; top: -3.823em; left: 0.649em;"><span class="mn" id="MathJax-Span-2957" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">1</span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span></span></span><span class="mo gbk" id="MathJax-Span-2958"></span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2959" style="padding-left: 0.164em;"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2960" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">(</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2961" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">k</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2962" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">)</span></span><span class="mo gbk" id="MathJax-Span-2963" style="padding-left: 0.164em;"></span><span class="msub" id="MathJax-Span-2964"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 1.08em; height: 0px;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.074em, 1000.81em, 4.151em, -999.997em); top: -3.984em; left: 0em;"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2965" style="font-family: MathJax_Script;">C<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.164em;"></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; top: -3.823em; left: 0.649em;"><span class="mn" id="MathJax-Span-2966" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">1</span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span></span></span><span class="mo gbk" id="MathJax-Span-2967"></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2968" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic; padding-left: 0.164em;">η<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span class="mo bbk" id="MathJax-Span-2969"></span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2970"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2971" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">(</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2972" style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">k</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2973" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">)</span></span><span class="mo gbk" id="MathJax-Span-2974" style="font-family: MathJax_Main; padding-left: 0.218em;">+</span><span class="munderover" id="MathJax-Span-2975" embellished="∑" style="padding-left: 0.218em;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 1.457em; height: 0px;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(2.858em, 1001.4em, 4.582em, -999.997em); top: -3.984em; left: 0em;"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2976" style="font-family: MathJax_Size2; vertical-align: 0em;">∑</span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.343em, 1001.24em, 4.367em, -999.997em); top: -2.907em; left: 0.11em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2977"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2978" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">p</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2979" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">=</span><span class="mn" id="MathJax-Span-2980" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">2</span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.235em, 1000.76em, 4.151em, -999.997em); top: -5.116em; left: 0.38em;"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2981" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">M<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.057em;"></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span></span></span><span class="mo gbk" id="MathJax-Span-2982" style="padding-left: 0.164em;"></span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2983" style="padding-left: 0.164em;"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2984" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: MathJax_Size4;">{</span></span><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2985"><span class="munderover" id="MathJax-Span-2986" embellished="∏"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 1.296em; height: 0px;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(2.858em, 1001.24em, 4.582em, -999.997em); top: -3.984em; left: 0em;"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2987" style="font-family: MathJax_Size2; vertical-align: 0em;">∏</span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.343em, 1001.19em, 4.367em, -999.997em); top: -2.907em; left: 0.003em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2988"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2989" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">q<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2990" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">=</span><span class="mn" id="MathJax-Span-2991" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">1</span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.235em, 1001.19em, 4.313em, -999.997em); top: -5.17em; left: 0.003em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2992"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-2993" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;">p</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-2994" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">−</span><span class="mn" id="MathJax-Span-2995" style="font-size: 70.7%; font-family: MathJax_Main;">1</span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;"></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.99em;" class="style2"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -1.622em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 3.941em;" class="style1"></span></span></nobr></span></div></div></div></td></tr>
</div>
```